# Symfony2 and 1969/04/27 date

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a form:

```
// AppBundle\Form\MyFormType.php
//...
->add('startDate', 'date', array(               
    'widget'=>'single_text'        
))
//....
```

Everything works fine except when the date is **1969/04/27**.

---

```
**Message:** This value is not valid.
**Origin:** startDate
**Cause:**
Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolation

Object(Symfony\Component\Form\Form).children[startDate] = 27/04/1969

**Caused by:**

Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\TransformationFailedException

Unable to reverse value for property path "startDate": Date parsing failed: U_PARSE_ERROR

**Caused by:**

Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\TransformationFailedException

Date parsing failed: U_PARSE_ERROR
```

---

I tested on versions 2.6 and 2.7 of Symfony2. Both the problem is the same. I also tested in different applications and the problem is similar.

Comment: In computer science dates are often wacky before 1970. Do other dates before 1970 work?

Comment: Yes, all except 1969/04/27

Comment: This error occurred if the given value (here `startDate`) is not a string, if the date could not be parsed or if the input timezone is not supported. (as mentioned in the [documentation](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/DataTransformer/DateTimeToStringTransformer.html#method_reverseTransform) => `reverseTransform`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you use php Intl. I solved the problem by using the symfony Intl.
Here is the code I use.
In the class DateTimeToLocalizedStringTransformer.php

```
use Symfony\Component\Intl\DateFormatter\IntlDateFormatter;



class DateTimeToLocalizedStringTransformer extends BaseDateTimeTransformer
{
     ....
     ....
     ....

     /**
     * Returns a preconfigured IntlDateFormatter instance.
     *
     * @return IntlDateFormatter
     *
     * @throws TransformationFailedException in case the date formatter can not be constructed.
     */
    protected function getIntlDateFormatter()
    {
        $dateFormat = $this->dateFormat;
        $timeFormat = $this->timeFormat;
        $timezone = $this->outputTimezone;
        $calendar = $this->calendar;
        $pattern = $this->pattern;
        //remove
        //$intlDateFormatter = new \IntlDateFormatter(\Locale::getDefault(), $dateFormat, $timeFormat, $timezone, $calendar, $pattern);
        //add
        $intlDateFormatter = new IntlDateFormatter('en', $dateFormat, $timeFormat, $timezone, $calendar, $pattern);

        // new \intlDateFormatter may return null instead of false in case of failure, see https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66323
        if (!$intlDateFormatter) {
            throw new TransformationFailedException(intl_get_error_message(), intl_get_error_code());
        }

        $intlDateFormatter->setLenient(false);

        return $intlDateFormatter;
    }
}
```

but this only works for the locale "en" until that is implemented for other locales